# como hacer para que las preguntas saltadas con pasapalabra vuelvan a la cola una y otra vez?

Tags: javascript

El código es una simulación del juego de pasapalabra, todo funciona bastante bien, o al menos lo que me pide el ejercicio que debo hacer, el problema lo tengo en las preguntas saltadas con la palabra pasapalabra, una vez echa toda la ronda de preguntas, las preguntas en las que se a introducido pasapalabra vuelven a aparecer, hasta ahí bien, lo que quiero es que en esas palabras si vuelvo a introducir pasapalabra vuelvan a la cola, el problema con el do while es que la palabra no se pone a la cola, sale de nuevo hasta que la responda o la falle, no se exactamente como usar el continue para que salte y vuelva a la cola la palabra y despues vuelva a aparecer. cualquier ayuda es de agradecer.

let questions = [

```
{ letter: "a", answer: "abducir", status: 0, question: "CON LA A. Dicho de una supuesta criatura extraterrestre: Apoderarse de alguien" },

{ letter: "b", answer: "bingo", status: 0, question: "CON LA B. Juego que ha sacado de quicio a todos los 'Skylabers' en las sesiones de precurso" },

{ letter: "c", answer: "churumbel", status: 0, question: "CON LA C. Niño, crío, bebé" },

{ letter: "d", answer: "diarrea", status: 0, question: "CON LA D. Anormalidad en la función del aparato digestivo caracterizada por frecuentes evacuaciones y su consistencia líquida" },

{ letter: "e", answer: "ectoplasma", status: 0, question: "CON LA E. Gelatinoso y se encuentra debajo de la membrana plasmática. Los cazafantasmas medían su radiación" },

{ letter: "f", answer: "facil", status: 0, question: "CON LA F. Que no requiere gran esfuerzo, capacidad o dificultad" },

{ letter: "g", answer: "galaxia", status: 0, question: "CON LA G. Conjunto enorme de estrellas, polvo interestelar, gases y partículas" },

{ letter: "h", answer: "harakiri", status: 0, question: "CON LA H. Suicidio ritual japonés por desentrañamiento" },

{ letter: "i", answer: "iglesia", status: 0, question: "CON LA I. Templo cristiano" },

{ letter: "j", answer: "jabali", status: 0, question: "CON LA J. Variedad salvaje del cerdo que sale en la película 'El Rey León', de nombre Pumba" },

{ letter: "k", answer: "kamikaze", status: 0, question: "CON LA K. Persona que se juega la vida realizando una acción temeraria" },

{ letter: "l", answer: "licantropo", status: 0, question: "CON LA L. Hombre lobo" },

{ letter: "m", answer: "misantropo", status: 0, question: "CON LA M. Persona que huye del trato con otras personas o siente gran aversión hacia ellas" },

{ letter: "n", answer: "necedad", status: 0, question: "CON LA N. Demostración de poca inteligencia" },

{ letter: "ñ", answer: "señal", status: 0, question: "CONTIENE LA Ñ. Indicio que permite deducir algo de lo que no se tiene un conocimiento directo." },

{ letter: "o", answer: "orco", status: 0, question: "CON LA O. Humanoide fantástico de apariencia terrible y bestial, piel de color verde creada por el escritor Tolkien" },

{ letter: "p", answer: "protoss", status: 0, question: "CON LA P. Raza ancestral tecnológicamente avanzada que se caracteriza por sus grandes poderes psíonicos del videojuego StarCraft" },

{ letter: "q", answer: "queso", status: 0, question: "CON LA Q. Producto obtenido por la maduración de la cuajada de la leche" },

{ letter: "r", answer: "raton", status: 0, question: "CON LA R. Roedor" },

{ letter: "s", answer: "stackoverflow", status: 0, question: "CON LA S. Comunidad salvadora de todo desarrollador informático" },

{ letter: "t", answer: "terminator", status: 0, question: "CON LA T. Película del director James Cameron que consolidó a Arnold Schwarzenegger como actor en 1984" },

{ letter: "u", answer: "unamuno", status: 0, question: "CON LA U. Escritor y filósofo español de la generación del 98 autor del libro 'Niebla' en 1914" },

{ letter: "v", answer: "vikingos", status: 0, question: "CON LA V. Nombre dado a los miembros de los pueblos nórdicos originarios de Escandinavia, famosos por sus incursiones y pillajes en Europa" },

{ letter: "w", answer: "sandwich", status: 0, question: "CONTIENE LA W. Emparedado hecho con dos rebanadas de pan entre las cuales se coloca jamón y queso" },

{ letter: "x", answer: "botox", status: 0, question: "CONTIENE LA X. Toxina bacteriana utilizada en cirujía estética" },

{ letter: "y", answer: "peyote", status: 0, question: "CONTIENE LA Y. Pequeño cáctus conocido por sus alcaloides psicoactivos utilizado de forma ritual y medicinal por indígenas americanos" },

{ letter: "z", answer: "zen", status: 0, question: "CON LA Z. Escuela de budismo que busca la experiencia de la sabiduría más allá del discurso racional" },]
```

```
let nombre;
let preg;
let pregp;
let acertadas = 0;
let falladas = 0;

let player = () =>{
    do{
    nombre = prompt('Bienvenido al juego de pasapalabra, indiquenos su nombre para continuar:');
    if(nombre === ''){
        window.alert('Indiquenos su nombre para continuar:');
    }else if(nombre === null){
        window.alert('Hasta la proxima')
        nombre;
    }else{
        
        console.log('Bienvenido: ' + nombre);
        pregunta();
        pasaPalabra();
    }
}while(nombre === '' || nombre === null);
};
//player();

let pregunta = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        preg = prompt('Responda: ' + questions[i].question);
        do {
            if (preg === '') {
                window.alert('Introduzca la palabra o pasapalabra para saltar a la siguiente definicion');
                preg = prompt('Responda: ' + questions[i].question);
            }
        } while (preg === '');

        if (preg.toLowerCase() === questions[i].answer) {
            acertadas++;
            questions[i].status = 1;
            window.alert('Ha hacertado la pregunta');
            questions[i].question;

        } else if (preg.toLowerCase() === 'pasapalabra') {
            questions[i].status = 0;
            window.alert('pregunta para la siguiente ronda');



        } else if (preg === 'end') {
            window.alert('No ha terminado la ronda y no entrara en el rankin');
            console.log('Ha hacertado: ' + acertadas + ' palabras');
            console.log('Ha fallado: ' + falladas + ' palabras');
            pregunta();


        } else {
            falladas++;
            questions[i].status = 2;
            window.alert('Respuesta incorrecta, la palabra que buscabamos era: ' + questions[i].answer);

        }

    }


};


let pasaPalabra = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {

            do {
                if (questions[i].status === 0) {
                    pregp = prompt('Responda preguntas saltadas: ' + questions[i].question);

                    if (pregp.toLowerCase() === 'pasapalabra') {
                        questions[i].status = 0;
                        window.alert('pregunta para la siguiente ronda');
                    
                    } else if (pregp.toLowerCase() === questions[i].answer) {
                        acertadas++;
                        questions[i].status = 1;
                        window.alert('Ha hacertado la pregunta');

                    } else {
                        falladas++;
                        questions[i].status = 2;
                        window.alert('Respuesta incorrecta, la palabra que buscabamos era: ' + questions[i].answer);
                    }

                }
                 } while (questions[i].status === 0);
                     if(questions[i].status === 0){
                        continue;  
                     }
                 
            }
        
    
    console.log('Ha hacertado: ' + acertadas + ' palabras');
    console.log('Ha fallado: ' + falladas + ' palabras');
    console.log('Ranking palabras acertadas');
    console.log(nombre+':' +' '+ acertadas + ' preguntas acertadas');
};
```

player();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola estuve viendo el código, esta buena la idea pero lo encare de otra manera, traté de mantener el flujo del juego en dos bucles anidados. La idea general es que el primer bucle (do while) no te permite salir hasta que no haya mas palabras pasadas mientras que el segundo bucle (for) itera las rondas. Agregué un array para almacenar las preguntas pasadas (pasapalabra). Además le agregué una variable para contar las rondas que puede ser útil. Aclaración: le cambie el nombre algunas variables para que queden en español. Saludos!

```
    let preguntas = [
    { letra: "a", respuesta: "abducir", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA A. Dicho de una supuesta criatura extraterrestre: Apoderarse de alguien" },
    
    { letra: "b", respuesta: "bingo", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA B. Juego que ha sacado de quicio a todos los 'Skylabers' en las sesiones de precurso" },
    
    { letra: "c", respuesta: "churumbel", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA C. Niño, crío, bebé" },
    
    { letra: "d", respuesta: "diarrea", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA D. Anormalidad en la función del aparato digestivo caracterizada por frecuentes evacuaciones y su consistencia líquida" },
    
    { letra: "e", respuesta: "ectoplasma", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA E. Gelatinoso y se encuentra debajo de la membrana plasmática. Los cazafantasmas medían su radiación" },
    
    { letra: "f", respuesta: "facil", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA F. Que no requiere gran esfuerzo, capacidad o dificultad" },
    
    { letra: "g", respuesta: "galaxia", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA G. Conjunto enorme de estrellas, polvo interestelar, gases y partículas" },
    
    { letra: "h", respuesta: "harakiri", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA H. Suicidio ritual japonés por desentrañamiento" },
    
    { letra: "i", respuesta: "iglesia", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA I. Templo cristiano" },
    
    { letra: "j", respuesta: "jabali", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA J. Variedad salvaje del cerdo que sale en la película 'El Rey León', de nombre Pumba" },
    
    { letra: "k", respuesta: "kamikaze", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA K. Persona que se juega la vida realizando una acción temeraria" },
    
    { letra: "l", respuesta: "licantropo", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA L. Hombre lobo" },
    
    { letra: "m", respuesta: "misantropo", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA M. Persona que huye del trato con otras personas o siente gran aversión hacia ellas" },
    
    { letra: "n", respuesta: "necedad", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA N. Demostración de poca inteligencia" },
    
    { letra: "ñ", respuesta: "señal", status: 0, pregunta: "CONTIENE LA Ñ. Indicio que permite deducir algo de lo que no se tiene un conocimiento directo." },
    
    { letra: "o", respuesta: "orco", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA O. Humanoide fantástico de apariencia terrible y bestial, piel de color verde creada por el escritor Tolkien" },
    
    { letra: "p", respuesta: "protoss", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA P. Raza ancestral tecnológicamente avanzada que se caracteriza por sus grandes poderes psíonicos del videojuego StarCraft" },
    
    { letra: "q", respuesta: "queso", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA Q. Producto obtenido por la maduración de la cuajada de la leche" },
    
    { letra: "r", respuesta: "raton", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA R. Roedor" },
    
    { letra: "s", respuesta: "stackoverflow", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA S. Comunidad salvadora de todo desarrollador informático" },
    
    { letra: "t", respuesta: "terminator", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA T. Película del director James Cameron que consolidó a Arnold Schwarzenegger como actor en 1984" },
    
    { letra: "u", respuesta: "unamuno", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA U. Escritor y filósofo español de la generación del 98 autor del libro 'Niebla' en 1914" },
    
    { letra: "v", respuesta: "vikingos", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA V. Nombre dado a los miembros de los pueblos nórdicos originarios de Escandinavia, famosos por sus incursiones y pillajes en Europa" },
    
    { letra: "w", respuesta: "sandwich", status: 0, pregunta: "CONTIENE LA W. Emparedado hecho con dos rebanadas de pan entre las cuales se coloca jamón y queso" },
    
    { letra: "x", respuesta: "botox", status: 0, pregunta: "CONTIENE LA X. Toxina bacteriana utilizada en cirujía estética" },
    
    { letra: "y", respuesta: "peyote", status: 0, pregunta: "CONTIENE LA Y. Pequeño cáctus conocido por sus alcaloides psicoactivos utilizado de forma ritual y medicinal por indígenas americanos" },
    
    { letra: "z", respuesta: "zen", status: 0, pregunta: "CON LA Z. Escuela de budismo que busca la experiencia de la sabiduría más allá del discurso racional" },]

let nombre;
let resp;
let acertadas = 0;
let falladas = 0;
let pasapalabra = [];
let ronda = 1;

let jugador = () =>{
    do{
    nombre = prompt('Bienvenido al juego de pasapalabra, indiquenos su nombre para continuar:');
    if(nombre === ''){
        window.alert('Indiquenos su nombre para continuar:');
    }else if(nombre === null){
        window.alert('Hasta la proxima')
        nombre;
    }else{        
        console.log('Bienvenido: ' + nombre);
        inicio();        
    }
}while(nombre === '' || nombre === null);
};
    
let inicio = () => {

    do {
        for (let i=0; i<preguntas.length; i++) {        
            
            if (preguntas[i].status === 0) {
                    
                resp = prompt('Responda: ' + preguntas[i].pregunta);               
                    
                if (resp === '') {
                    do {           
                        window.alert('Introduzca la palabra o pasapalabra para saltar a la siguiente definicion');                
                        resp = prompt('Responda: ' + preguntas[i].pregunta);           
                    } while (resp === ''); 
                } 
    
                if (resp === 'end') {
                    window.alert('No ha terminado la ronda y no entrara en el rankin');
                    console.log('Ha hacertado: ' + acertadas + ' palabras');
                    console.log('Ha fallado: ' + falladas + ' palabras');
                    pasapalabra = [];
                    preguntas.forEach(el => {
                        el.status = 0;
                    })
                    inicio();
                    
                } else if (resp.toLowerCase() === preguntas[i].respuesta) {
                    acertadas++;
                    preguntas[i].status = 1;
                    if (pasapalabra.includes(preguntas[i])) {
                        pasapalabra.splice(pasapalabra.indexOf(preguntas[i]), 1);                        
                    }
                    window.alert('Ha hacertado la pregunta');                        
                } else if (resp.toLowerCase() === 'pasapalabra') {
                    preguntas[i].status = 0;
                    if (!pasapalabra.includes(preguntas[i])) {
                        pasapalabra.push(preguntas[i]);                        
                    }
                    window.alert('pregunta para la siguiente ronda');
                } else{
                    falladas++;
                    preguntas[i].status = 2;
                    if (pasapalabra.includes(preguntas[i])) {
                        pasapalabra.splice(pasapalabra.indexOf(preguntas[i]), 1);                        
                    }                    
                    window.alert('Respuesta incorrecta, la palabra que buscabamos era: ' + preguntas[i].respuesta);                               
                }
            }
        }; 
        
        ronda++;
    
    } while (pasapalabra.length !== 0);

    prompt('Ha completado el juego en: ' + ronda + ' rondas\n' +
        'Ha acertado: ' + acertadas + ' palabras\n' +
        'Ha fallado: ' + falladas + ' palabras\n' +
        'Ranking palabras acertadas\n'+
        nombre+':' +' '+ acertadas + ' preguntas acertadas')
}

jugador();
```

Comment: muchas gracias por responder y por tu tiempo, me a ayudado mucho tu solucion.